# Constructor gets called twice when dynamically instantiating class

Tags: python

I am using `importlib` & `getattr` to dynamically create an instance of a class. But, when i run `Proxy.py` that is provided below, the constructor gets called twice and i get duplicate results. Thanks in advance. (Python 3.6.1)

**Result**

```
inside Cproxy contructor
inside Cproxy read()
inside Cproxy contructor
inside Cproxy read()
```

**Runner.py**

```
import importlib
class Crunner:
    def __init__(self, nameofmodule, nameofclass):        
        self.run(nameofmodule, nameofclass)

    def run(self, nameofmodule, nameofclass):
        module = importlib.import_module(nameofmodule)            
        class_ = getattr(module, nameofclass)
        instance = class_()
        instance.read()
```

**Proxy.py**

```
from Runner import Crunner
class Cproxy:
    def __init__(self):
        print("inside Cproxy contructor")    
    def read():
        print("inside Cproxy read()")


Crunner("Proxy", "Cproxy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy module is imported twice - once as `__main__` (when you run `python Proxy.py`) and once as `Proxy` (when it's imported by `Crunner`).

The solution is simple: guard the call to `Crunner()` so it's only executed when `Proxy` is used as script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Crunner("Proxy", "Cproxy")
```

Comment: Thanks again @bruno desthuilliers for the quick solution and the clarification.